# Crystal Report - Sub Report - Subtract Suppress Field

Tags: crystal-reports, subreport, subtraction

I have a report with 2 columns:

```
ID-------Value
1--------$1000
2--------$800
3--------$500
4--------$700
5--------Should equals $2500 (sum of records 1+2+4)
```

I did suppress record 3 so the results are showing

```
ID-------Value
1--------$1000
2--------$800
4--------$700
5--------$3000 (since it is summing 1, 2, 3, 4, 5).
```

I want to find a way to subtract the $500 from the $3000, knowing that record 5 is not a total, it is also in the report details. 
Any ideas?

Comment: is the ID database field or it is the record number in crystal reports?

Comment: show us the design of your report. and how did you supress the 3? did you fix the value?

Comment: The ID is a database field. The suppress was done in the details by adding this rule: `code` If {.ID} = '3' then 
TRUE
Else False; `code`